# How to delete an item from a list and start counting from the next item?

Tags: python, list

For an example, I want to create a FLAMES game. Below is the list.

['F','L','A','M','E','S']

When I tried to remove the 11th item, The first letter to be eliminated is "E". Then the counting has to start from the letter "S". I don't know how to build a logic for that.

The counting has to be repeated over and over until we get a single item. After we popped the 11th item "E", the counting has to start from "S" and the 11th item would be "S" this time. Now "S" has to be removed and the counting has to start from "F" then the 11th letter would be "A". After that remove "F" and "L". Finally, the letter "M" should remain. That's the logic I want

Here is what I tried initially.

```
x = 11
sample = ['f','l','a','m','e','s']
print len(sample)
empty = []
while True:
    print sample
    if len(sample) == 1:
        print sample
        print "Congratulations!!! Your result is %s"%(sample[0].upper())
        break
    elif len(sample)>= x:
        sample.pop(x-1)
    elif len(sample)< x:
        y = x % len(sample)
        sample.pop(y-1)
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: "M" is my desired output. After we popped out the 11th item (i.e. "E") then the counting starts from "S" then the 11th item would be "S" now. This popping and counting should continue until we get one item left on this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function:

```
sample = ['f','l','a','m','e','s']

def  last_item(sample, x):
    rest = 0
    a = 0
    while (len(sample) >1):
        rest = (x+rest-a) % len(sample)
        if rest == 0:
            rest = len(sample)
        print('element eliminated', sample[rest - 1])
        sample.pop(rest - 1)
        a = 1
    return sample


print(last_item(sample, 5))
```

Output x = 5:

```
element eliminated e
element eliminated m
element eliminated s
element eliminated l
element eliminated a
['f']
```

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But the counting has to be repeated over and over until we get a single item. After we popped the item "e", the counting has to start from "S" and the 11th item would be "S" this time. Now "S" has to be removed and the counting has to start from "F" then the 11th letter would be "A". After that remove "F" and "L". Finally, the letter "M" should remain. That's the logic I want. :)

Comment: @VasanthPrabakar I just edited, I think now works properly.

Comment: Umm. But it returns "M" even If we assign any number to "X". For example, I assigned x=5. It should return "F", but it returns "M" again.

Comment: @VasanthPrabakar Edited. With x=5, the result would not be "a"?

Comment: No. It would be "F". 1st elimination: E
2nd elimination: M
3rd elimination: S
4th elimination: L
5th elimination: A

Comment: @VasanthPrabakar there was a problem when the last element is removed, I add a conditional that I think fixes it.

Comment: Great! I think the logic works flawlessly now. I assigned different numbers. The output comes as I expected. Thanks :)